# How to route a nested resource route to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, routes, controller, nested

I'm working on implementing boards.

Now I have BoardsController and PostsController.

By default, posts are nested by boards.

I want all board's post list have their special route using same PostsController

so I did this in route.rb
`resources :notice, :controller => "posts", :board_id => 1

resources :faq, :controller => "posts", :board_id => 2

resources :qna, :controller => "posts", :board_id => 3`

At first, it seems to work. But I realized a problem.
because i used same 'PostsController' in these resources.

Codes related to path are same when doing controller's action

like,

posts_controller


`def create
        @post = Board.find(params[:board_id]).posts.build(params[:post])`

```
    if @post.save
        redirect_to board_posts_path(@post.board_id)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

when I go to localhost:3000/notice/new, it works fine

but when I submitted the new post, controller redirects to localhost:3000/boards/1/posts/

because of  `redirect_to board_posts_path(@post.board_id)`

and that's not what I want.

I could handle this using if statements, but it seems messy.

Is there any proper solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `self.send` on the controller to dynamically resolve the path by the post type. Assuming you have the type of the created post in a string ( I didn't understand from your question if Notice < Post and if you use Single Table Inheritance):

```
post_type = # Get the specific post type ( "notice, faq ...")
redirect_to self.send("#{post_type}_path", @post.board_id)
```

Comment: Be aware that a send method might be able to expose your class entirely and can be called from a simple get request submitting any board_id. or class method.